# Issue on connecting local mysql-workbench with docker mariadb

Tags: docker, mysql-workbench

Currently I'm facing an issue trying to connect to my mariadb database running in an docker-container.

My Local Information:

- OS: Windows 10
- Docker-Toolkit
- Trying to connect from MySql Workbench
  [Workbench config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIxL9.png)
- Docker ps returns following:

[Docker List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqSGt.png)

Testing the connection I only get the error message "Failed to Connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root. Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061)".
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDTqa.png)

Trying to connect using MySql-Workbench from my virtual machine (Ubuntu) it works without problems.

Does someone have an idea how to solve that issue?

**Update**:

I started the docker container using docker-compose:

```
 mysql:
image: mariadb:10.1
ports:
  - "127.0.0.1:3306:3306"
environment:
  MYSQL_DATABASE: databasename
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pw
volumes:
  - myproject-mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
networks:
  - back
logging:
  options:
    max-size: "25m"
    max-file: "4"
```

**Update 2:**

Also tried to connect using Squirel with MariaDB Driver. Also doesn't work. It seems, that windows can't find the 127.0.0.1:3306.

"Telnet 127.0.0.1 3306" also responded  with a not found message.

What I'm doing wrong here?
Is it maybe due to the docker-toolbox and Virtualbox usage?

**Solution:**

Hey all, thank you for your help. I tried to put my won information into a blog-post hoping that it can help someone: [Solution](https://sascha-franke.blogspot.de/2018/01/connecting-native-database-client-to_18.html)

Comment: Can you also provide the `docker run` command that you have used?

Comment: I'm using docker-compose. I updated my description by the compose configs.

Comment: try removing the "127.0.0.1" from the port config

Comment: Tried to remove the config. In that case the fallback ip 0.0.0.0:3306 doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*What I'm doing wrong here? Is it maybe due to the docker-toolbox and Virtualbox usage?*

One of the *Cons* mentioned here: [Should You Install Docker With the Docker Toolbox or Docker for Mac / Windows?](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/should-you-use-the-docker-toolbox-or-docker-for-mac-windows) states:

> ### Docker Toolbox
>
> #### Cons
>
> - Not a native solution, so you’ll need to access your Docker Machine’s IP address if you’re developing web apps. Example: `192.168.99.100` instead of `localhost`.

and I think the same is also mentioned here: [Docker Toolbox - Localhost not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42866013/docker-toolbox-localhost-not-working)

> In Toolbox, nothing will be `localhost`, and will be `192.168.99.100` by default, since it's running a Linux VM in VirtualBox.

Comment: Great. Many Thanks. You gave me exactly that information I needed to solve my problem. Thank you.