# connect to server runned in windows docker container

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox, docker-for-windows

I am a newbie with docker. I need to use it at windows 7*64 , via `docker toolbox`. **I need to make a connection to server below:**

Run the server:

```
docker run -p 4444:4444 mycontainerWithServer
```

After this i open new docker toolbox window and try to connect to `localhost:4444`. I get ConnectionRefused error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker Toolbox - Localhost not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42866013/docker-toolbox-localhost-not-working)

Comment: probably, yes, i quickly tried that solution and it seems to be working. I couldn't find it before, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using the Docker toolbox you don't access your containers on `localhost`. The toolbox uses `192.168.99.100` by default because it is running on a Linux VM. Try replacing localhost with the VM IP.