# Docker compose services not accessible from localhost

Tags: docker, docker-compose, localhost, port

I have the following docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        volumes:
            - "${DOCKER_VOLUMES_PATH}/mysql:/var/lib/mysql:cached"
        command: --sql_mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        environment:
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=mcoins
            - MYSQL_USER=mcoins
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mcoins
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mcoins
        restart: always
        networks:
            - development

    redis:
        image: redis:3.2-alpine
        volumes:
            - "${DOCKER_VOLUMES_PATH}/redis:/data:cached"
        ports:
            - 5379:5379
        restart: always
        networks:
            - development

networks:
    development:
```

and when i try to access localhost:3306 or localhost:5379 from my machine that doesn't work

this is what i get from docker ps :

[docker ps command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHGHA.png)

Comment: could you post what u get from  `docker ps`?

Comment: i added a result of the command

Comment: Do you see any errors when you check the logs by `docker logs -f container-id` ? If no, then you container mostly running well. Then i would login into the container check wether im able to access the mysql and redis inside the container

Comment: the logs don't show any errors

Comment: what do you see when you execute this `redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5379`

Comment: the command stucks at the cursor flashing

Comment: Login into the container and check service is running inside the container. Also what is the exact error you see when you try to access the services from the host machine?

Comment: i get website not accessible and the images doesn't provide a tty to access via docker exec

Comment: Are you running Docker Toolbox perchance?

Comment: yes that's the case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker Toolbox - Localhost not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42866013/docker-toolbox-localhost-not-working)

Comment: i tried that but that address  isn't accessible either and when i check VBox the default image isn't even running

Comment: Any solution for that problem?

Comment: @eldios1981 yes you should try to reinstall VBox and get rid of all the network related and reinstall docker then it ll work