# Developing react app via docker container

Tags: reactjs, docker

I am trying to develop a simple react app and I am trying to use docker for running a development server, but it is not connecting up in the browser

Here is the Dockerfile.dev

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]

EXPOSE 3000
```

Here are the two commands to create and run the container

```
docker build -f Dockerfile.dev .
docker run -p 3000:3000 <image_id>
```

It's starting a development server as the normal npm start does but it is not running in the browser at localhost:3000

Comment: Can you share the output of your `npm run start` command ?

Comment: is your app running on port 3000?

Comment: Are you using Docker Toolbox?

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, I am using Docker Toolbox.

Comment: @ElvinValiev Yes

Comment: @MarcABOUCHACRA It's exactly same when we run it normally.

Comment: If you’re using Docker Toolbox, try http://192.168.99.100:3000 (or whatever IP address `docker-machine ip` returns).  It runs a separate VM and `localhost` won’t reach it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You container will exist if you did not mention `-it` or `-dit` (if its not typo in question). The reason being stopped immediately because bash can't find any pseudo terminal to be allocated. You have to specify `-it` or `-dit` so that bash or sh can be allocated to a pseudo-terminal.

```
docker run --name test -p 3000:3000 <image_id>
```

If you run `docker ps | grep test` you will see in the output

`"/bin/bash"              {some} seconds ago       Exited (0) {some} seconds ago`

Now try to run with

```
docker run --name test -dit -p 3000:3000 <image_id>
```

or

```
docker run --name test -it -p 3000:3000 <image_id>
```

Good to go [localhost:3000](http://localhost:3000)

**Updated:**

For window, docker toolbox follows these steps.

Click the appropriate machine (probably the one labeled "default")
Settings

- Network > Adapter 1 > Advanced > Port Forwarding
- Click "+" to add a
  new Rule Set Host Port 3000 & Guest Port 3000; be sure to leave Host
  IP and Guest IP empty

Run the command:

```
docker run -dit -p 3000:3000 ${image_id}
```

[docker-toolbox-localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42866013/docker-toolbox-localhost-not-working)

Comment: It's still not working, by the way, I am using docker toolbox on windows.

Comment: okay so this is the issue with docker toolbox here is the answer for your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42866013/docker-toolbox-localhost-not-working

Comment: updated pls check or follow the question for further investigation