# I am Trying to connect to pgadmin from the localhost server

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I'v tried to connect to **pgadmin** from the browser using the port that I exposed *(localhost:**8091**)* but the page displays

> **This site can’t be reached**
>
> ***localhost refused to connect***

- I am using **windows10 Home**.
- I created two containers one for the **pgadmin** and the second for the **postgres**.

$ docker ps

```
        CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS             PORTS                           NAMES
        01eec2da2408        dpage/pgadmin4      "/entrypoint.sh"         2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8091->80/tcp   mypgadmin
        fb282d9c392a        postgres            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   43 hours ago        Up 43 hours         0.0.0.0:9090->5432/tcp          mypg
```

Comment: make sure your server is running.

Comment: the server is started

Comment: If you're using Windows 10 Home, are you using Docker Toolbox; and if so, does [Docker Toolbox - Localhost not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42866013/docker-toolbox-localhost-not-working) address your issue?

Comment: Can you please provide your docker compose file?

Answer (score 0):

Try http://127.0.0.1:8091
For some reason my pgadmin server no longer responds to localhost, only IP-adress. If anyone knows why, please comment :-)